# For loop adding new line

Tags: java, for-loop

EDIT: Sorry about not being clear where the extra new line happens

I have a for loop that reads from different arrays in order to make a long string to display. The format of the string should be like this

```
Question X
Your answer was: Y
Correct answer was: Z

Question XX
Your answer was: YY
Correct answer was: ZZ

....
```

However when the string is produced it starts off fine but it gets to have an extra space as shown in the pattern below

```
....

Question X
Your answer was: Y
Correct answer was: Z

Question XX
Your answer was: YY
Correct answer was: ZZ

Question XXX
Your answer was: YYY

Correct answer was: ZZZ

Question XXXX
Your answer was: YYYY
Correct answer was: ZZZ

Question XXXXX
Your answer was: YYYYY

Correct answer was: ZZZZZ
```

...

This is the code I have to produce this:

```
 for(int x=1;x<11;x++){
      if(x==10) 
      {
       longResultsString+="Question " + x + " " + isCorrect[9] + "\nYour  answer was: " + detailedResultsUserChoices[9] +" \nCorrect answer was: " + answerChoices[9][4];

      }
      else{
      longResultsString+="Question " + x + " "+isCorrect[x-1] + "\nYour answer was: " + detailedResultsUserChoices[x-1] +" \nCorrect answer was: " + answerChoices[x-1][4] + "\n\n";

      }
 }
```

and I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions for what would cause this behavior

Comment: Apologies for including the superfluous `android` tag. Removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
  sb.append("Question " + (x + 1) + " " + isCorrect[x] + "\nYour  answer was: " + detailedResultsUserChoices[x] + "\nCorrect answer was: " + answerChoices[x][4]);
  if (x != 9) {
    sb.append("\n");
  }
}

sb.toString(); // the string you want
```

This may not even fix your code (a concrete example in the question would be nice), but it might help with having good code practices:

- 0 index loops
- Use StringBuilder when you are building up a long string like this in a loop
- DRY (Don't repeat yourself) - you just want one less newline at the end, right? Then no need to copy all the rest of the common statement in the else part.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. However I am unable to provide a concrete example because I get different behavior each time when running, but what is similar is that every other time the loop runs it adds the extra line and it starts after what seems to be a random number of iterations

Answer (score 0):

You had an extra /n in your else statement.. Try this now. Your code is slightly different from the output there so its hard to tell

```
for(int x=1;x<11;x++){
  if(x==11) 
  {
   longResultsString+="Question " + x + " " + isCorrect[9] + "\nYour  answer was: " + detailedResultsUserChoices[9] +" \nCorrect answer was: " + answerChoices[9][4];

  }
  else{
  longResultsString+="Question " + x + " "+isCorrect[x-1] + "\nYour answer was: " + detailedResultsUserChoices[x-1] +" \nCorrect answer was: " + answerChoices[x-1][4] + "\n";

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The value within

```
detailedResultsUserChoices[x-1]
```

has an embedded CR char

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int x=1;x<=11;x++){
  if(x==11) 
  {
   longResultsString+="Question " + x + " " + isCorrect[9] + "\nYour  answer was: " + detailedResultsUserChoices[9] +" \nCorrect answer was: " + answerChoices[9][4];

  }
  else{
  longResultsString+="Question " + x + " "+isCorrect[x-1] + "\nYour answer was: " + detailedResultsUserChoices[x-1] +" \nCorrect answer was: " + answerChoices[x-1][4] + "\n";

  }
```

Remove the second \n (new line) escape character from the else statement and change you for loop condition so that the if condition will have a chance.